# How to build a Framework before the App gets build in one step with the latest Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

i have a project folder with a `src` and a `example` subfolder. In `src` lives a `Framework.xcodeproj` file, which needs to be build before the `App.xcodeproj` gets build.

Is there a way to tell Xcode to first build the Framework and after that, build the App? I tried to drag n drop the `Framework.xcodeproj` into the `App.xcodeproj` and add it to the *Target Dependencies* but this is not really working. I run into error messages and missing files.

Is a *shellscript* within a *Run Script Phase* a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you using an Xcode Workspace, or an Xcode Project? A workspace is the way to go. You'll want to make a workspace containing both your App and Framework projects. Just add your Framework's built product to your App's linked frameworks, and Xcode is smart enough to build your Framework as a prerequisite to your app (you don't even need to add it to Target Dependencies). It works really well, and workspaces are the only way to go if you've got an App + Framework.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will give this a try. Because we are using CocoaPods i am using a Workspace already.